# Repository classes aren't getting disposed in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm using MVC + EF + ServiceStack.  I recently discovered some issues with EF context and stale data.  I have repository classes that I'm injecting in the controllers with RequestScope.None.  The repository classes aren't getting disposed by the IoC after it is used.

ServiceStack's IoC docs states that if it implements IDisposeable the container should call the dispose method after it is used.  I'm wondering if this behavior is different since I'm not calling the objects from within a service stack service?

Registering the repo here:

```
 container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<LicenseRepository, ILicenseRepository>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class LicenseController : BaseController
{
    public ILicenseRepository licenseRepo { get; set; }  //injected by IOC
    private ILog Logger;

    public LicenseController()
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var license = licenseRepo.GetLicense(id);
        if (license == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(license);
    }
    ...
}
```

Typical repository class: (dbcontext is getting instantiated in base class)

```
    public class LicenseRepository: RepositoryBase<LicensingDBContext>, ILicenseRepository,IDisposable
{

    public License GetLicense(Guid id)
    {
        return DataContext.Licenses.Find(id);
    }

      ....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used ServiceStack but use AutoFac extensively and in that tool lifetime is an important config. Is it possible ServiceStack isn't disposing because it isn't aware of the lifetime requirements?

Comment: ServiceStack uses Funq for the IoC.  I'm specifying ReuseScope.None which should dispose immediately after use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack only calls `Dispose()` on dependencies resolved within ServiceStack Requests, i.e. it tracks any disposables resolved from Funq and disposes of them at the end of a ServiceStack request.

Outside the context of a ServiceStack request, ServiceStack doesn't have ownership of it, i.e. it can't know when it's used or no longer needed. Therefore any dependencies resolved needs to be explicitly disposed.

Comment: Well... don't think you can get a better answer than one from the developer of the framework :)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it alright.  I've got a bunch of singletons hanging out in all my controllers.

Comment: @Mythz, is this supposed to handle the disposing within controllers or just the injection?              
            'ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));'

Comment: @brussell Just autowiring of the Controller. I'd look at overriding the MVC Controllers `Dispose(bool)` and dispose any Disposable deps in there.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using your repo within a using block or explicitly calling dispose on the repo, I would think to get immediate disposal you would need to do one or the other, if it's anything like other implementations of IDisposable.

I'm not familiar with ServiceStack, but like any other IDisposable object you can dispose of it as such (when having it within a using block isn't an option):

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var license = licenseRepo.GetLicense(id);
    licenseRepo.Dispose();
    if (license == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(license);
}
```